# How to enable macOS keyboard shortcuts in Juno?

Tags: release-juno, keyboard-shortcuts

I installed Juno on a Macbook Late 2007, and even enabling the "English Macintosh" keyboard, the shortcuts are not the same, for example CMD+C and CMD+V to copy and paste, and to enter Latin characters such as "éôãç..."

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I can address the copy/paste situation, but the Latin issue may require a more in-depth resolution that involves learning xkb and will be outside the scope of my answer as I have not worked that much with providing compose key or multi-language support.

For copy and paste to work with Juno or most any distro you can use [xkeysnail](https://github.com/mooz/xkeysnail) or use my [kinto](https://github.com/rbreaves/kinto) app which will use either xkeysnail or xkb to setup keymap switching like you are wanting.

A short example of some remapping I do with it, but you will need the entirety of kinto if you want it to fully configure things for you as it will also setup xkeysnail as a systemd service, something xkeysnail will not do and the complete kinto.py config file will manage several different keymaps for the proper apps by default.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
from xkeysnail.transform import *

terminals = ["gnome-terminal","konsole","io.elementary.terminal","terminator","sakura","guake","tilda","xterm","eterm","kitty"]
terminals = [term.casefold() for term in terminals]
termStr = "|".join(str(x) for x in terminals)

define_conditional_modmap(lambda wm_class: wm_class.casefold() not in terminals,{
    # Default Mac/Win
    Key.LEFT_ALT: Key.RIGHT_CTRL,   # WinMac
    Key.LEFT_META: Key.LEFT_ALT,    # WinMac
    Key.LEFT_CTRL: Key.LEFT_META,   # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_ALT: Key.RIGHT_CTRL,  # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_META: Key.RIGHT_ALT,  # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_CTRL: Key.RIGHT_META, # WinMac
})

# [Conditional modmap] Change modifier keys in certain applications
define_conditional_modmap(re.compile(termStr, re.IGNORECASE), {
    # Default Mac/Win
    Key.LEFT_ALT: Key.RIGHT_CTRL,   # WinMac
    Key.LEFT_META: Key.LEFT_ALT,    # WinMac
    Key.LEFT_CTRL: Key.LEFT_CTRL,   # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_ALT: Key.RIGHT_CTRL,  # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_META: Key.RIGHT_ALT,  # WinMac
    Key.RIGHT_CTRL: Key.LEFT_CTRL,  # WinMac
})

define_keymap(None,{
    # Cmd Tab - App Switching Default
    # App switching is mapped to use Ctrl+F13 in place of Tab
    # this avoids Alt+Tab from still activating App Switching
    # Ctrl+Tab is also used for In-App tab switching often times
    # RCtrl is also mapped in Cmd key position only
    K("RC-Tab"): K("RC-F13"),
    K("RC-Shift-Tab"): K("RC-Shift-F13"),
    K("RC-Grave"): K("RC-Shift-F13"),
    # In-App Tab switching
    # K("M-Tab"): K("C-Tab"),                   # Chromebook - In-App Tab switching
    # K("M-Shift-Tab"): K("C-Shift-Tab"),       # Chromebook - In-App Tab switching
    K("Super-Tab"): K("LC-Tab"),                # Default
    K("Super-Shift-Tab"): K("LC-Shift-Tab"),    # Default
    K("LC-Grave") : K("LC-Shift-Tab"),
})
```